# Постоянная и ровная "Accuracy"

Tags: нейронные-сети, keras

Построил СНС для определения координат зрачка, скажите пожалуйста почему у меня точность (Accuracy) всегда одинакова, а потеря (Loss) варьируется и если верить то в лучшую сторону (уменьшается), и в чём тут может быть ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Входные данные:**

- Изображение глаза (50 фото, 80x60, чёрно-белое, качество отличное):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Массив координат(x,y) точек куда "смотрит" глаз:

> [[165, 101], [481, 545], [736, 508], [743, 92], [802, 363], [1383,
> 296], [402, 549] , ... , [1179, 398], [711, 93], [453, 295], [914, 691]]

**Собственно сама модель:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(80,60,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

 
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='softmax'))

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

batch_size = 256
epochs = 5 #Пробовал 5, 15, 25, 100

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(images, answers, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

**Вывод:**

```
Epoch 1/15
55/55 [==============================] - 30s 542ms/step - loss: 0.0693 - acc: 0.4545
Epoch 2/15
55/55 [==============================] - 17s 318ms/step - loss: 0.0675 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 3/15
55/55 [==============================] - 17s 315ms/step - loss: 0.0661 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 4/15
55/55 [==============================] - 18s 325ms/step - loss: 0.0650 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 5/15
55/55 [==============================] - 17s 314ms/step - loss: 0.0640 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 6/15
55/55 [==============================] - 18s 321ms/step - loss: 0.0626 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 7/15
55/55 [==============================] - 19s 336ms/step - loss: 0.0619 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 8/15
55/55 [==============================] - 17s 301ms/step - loss: 0.0602 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 9/15
55/55 [==============================] - 16s 290ms/step - loss: 0.0596 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 10/15
55/55 [==============================] - 16s 292ms/step - loss: 0.0589 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 11/15
55/55 [==============================] - 20s 357ms/step - loss: 0.0582 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 12/15
55/55 [==============================] - 18s 319ms/step - loss: 0.0567 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 13/15
55/55 [==============================] - 18s 325ms/step - loss: 0.0561 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 14/15
55/55 [==============================] - 18s 321ms/step - loss: 0.0558 - acc: 0.7636
Epoch 15/15
55/55 [==============================] - 18s 327ms/step - loss: 0.0548 - acc: 0.7636
```

P.S. Я думал насчёт того, что фотографий мало для обучения, но тогда бы точность была бы просто мала и варьировалась.

P.P.S. Данные нормализовал как обычно, изображения /= 255, массив /= максимальное значение в массиве.

Comment: можете выложить  набор для обучения модели?

Comment: @MaxU можно в ЛС кинуть (на почту например)? :)

Comment: @MaxU ну ладно http://rgho.st/67QfLgRGK )

Comment: извините пожалуйста, тупой сайт, вот это точно заработает https://yadi.sk/d/iMQwpHP33ad7xj

Comment: попробую поиграться с этими данными когда буду посвободнее...

Comment: а где взять координаты - `answers`?

Comment: @MaxU спасибо :)

Comment: @MaxU крч сделал прогу в которой перемещается белый квадрат и при нажатии на который, записывается в файл одновременно его координаты и делается фото, могу скинуть если нужно

Comment: Исходные изображения в разрешении в 4k, могу тоже скинуть, ну там сечатку видно и там точно уже в ЛС )))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82354/discussion-between-maxu-and-alex-rudenkiy).